# Getting Angular Material to work in angular library

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-library

I'm trying to get Angular Material to work within an Angular Library.

These are the steps I have taken:

1. Create project

> ```
> ng new test-project
> ```

2. Add Angular Material

> ```
> ng add @angular/material
> ```

3. Create Library

> `ng g library test-lib`

4. Add reference to angular material to peer dependencies within test-lib package.json file

> ```
>   "peerDependencies": {
>     "@angular/common": "^7.2.0",
>     "@angular/core": "^7.2.0",
>     "@angular/material": "^7.3.7"
>   }
> ```

5. Within test-lib-component add the html for a Angular Material CheckBox

> ```
> @Component({
>   selector: 'test-lib',
>   template: `
>     <p>
>       test!
>     </p>
>     <mat-checkbox>my checkbox</mat-checkbox>
>   `,
>   styles: []
> })
> ```

6. Build library

> `ng build test-lib --watch`

7. Within application app.module add references for component from test-lib

> ```
> import { TestLibComponent } from 'test-lib'
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [
>     AppComponent,
>     TestLibComponent
>   ],
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     BrowserAnimationsModule
>   ],
>   providers: [],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```

8. Within the library project, within the test-lib.module I add the references to the Angular Material CheckBox Module

> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { ControlLibraryComponent } from './control-library.component';
> import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
>
> @NgModule({
>   declarations: [TestLibComponent],
>   imports: [
>     MatCheckboxModule
>   ],
>   exports: [TestLibComponent]
> })
> export class TestLibModule { }
> ```

9. Finally within the main apps app.component.html file I add the html for the library using the correct selector

> `<test-lib></test-lib>`

I now run the app and I receive the following error:

'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

This is obviously the standard message when a reference is missing but as I've added them I'm wondering what else I need to do within a library to get this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to export the `MatCheckboxModule` from the `TestLibModule`? 

Try `exports: [TestLibComponent, MatCheckboxModule]`

Comment: I've just tried and I still receive the error.

Comment: I think you need to export as per this: `export { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox'`;

Comment: Do you mean in the public-api.ts file?

Comment: Just tried, same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updating answer after local coding:

I tried all the steps mentioned in the question by you and I could run the application without any error. However, I need to update some of your code as below:

#### 1. app.module

```
import { TestLibModule } from 'test-lib';    // <-- this

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    TestLibModule    // <-- this
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

#### 2. Make sure of the selector name

```
<lib-test-lib></lib-test-lib>
```

#### 3. test-lib.module

No change required

#### 4. Screenshot with `<mat-checkbox>my checkbox</mat-checkbox>`

[image]

#### 5. Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you share https://stackblitz.com snippet for better understanding?

Comment: I can't create a library within stackblitz

Comment: Okay, let me follow your steps and then get back to you. I am sure this is something very minor missing.

Comment: Thanks. Really appreciate this. I also believe it'll be something simple.

Comment: I've updated the answer with some updated. Please try.

Comment: Add the Angular Material Checkbox within the component (Sorry missed this on my steps, I'll add it now)

Comment: Please approve the answer if it is the fix for you. Thanks :)

Comment: See step 5.  Does it still work after you've added the checkbox?

Comment: This is my problem

Comment: See step 5 (sorry)

Comment: And that is in your test-lib component? I don't understand why yours works.

Comment: Sorry! I just don't see why it doesn't work for me. I'm going to start again

Comment: OK, I think I'm working. Your instructions in step 1 of your answer helped. Let me just check things and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm sorted now.

Comment: Glad by helping you :)